# Numpy array generation in Pyython

Tags: python, numpy

Create a NumPy array of random numbers, whose dimension attribute is equal to 4?

How can I set the dimension in this? Can anyone help me with the one-line code?

Answer (score 1):

You can give the dimensions of the data when creating it. The following will give you 4 dimensional data since I provided 4 values.

```py
import numpy as np
                        
array = np.random.randn(3, 2, 2, 3)
print(array)
```